# How to return custom JSON output in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to return custom json with the following structure

```
[ { 
'yesterday': [{'teams': "team a -team b", 'start_time': "0: 11", 'pick': "X2", 'score': "1:4", 'odds': 1.25, 'won_or_lost': "won", 'date': "2019-01-8"}],

'today': [{'teams': "team a -team b", 'start_time': "0: 11", 'pick': "X2", 'score': "1:4", 'odds': 1.25, 'won_or_lost': "won", 'date': "2019-01-8"}],

'tomorrow': [{'teams': "team a -team b", 'start_time': "0: 11", 'pick': "X2", 'score': "1:4", 'odds': 1.25, 'won_or_lost': "won", 'date': "2019-01-8"}]
}]
```

The following is my code:

## serializer.py

```
class GamesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AllGames
        fields = ('teams', 'start_time', 'pick',
                  'score', 'odds', 'won_or_lost', 'date')


class GamesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    today_date = date_picker

    yesterday = AllGames.objects.filter(
        date=today_date(-1)).order_by('start_time', 'teams')
    today = AllGames.objects.filter(
        date=today_date(0)).order_by('start_time', 'teams')
    tomorrow = AllGames.objects.filter(
        date=today_date(1)).order_by('start_time', 'teams')

    queryset = [yesterday, today, tomorrow]
    serializer_class = GamesSerializer
```

## Current Output

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

How can I modify my **GamesSerializer** to return the custom output as shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to find the answer for this I used `Viewset` instead of `ModelViewSet` as suggested by [@jay-vasant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7870866/jay-vasant) and then `overrode list` method above to customize the output like I wanted.
This is my `GamesViewSet` after update.

```
class GamesViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
def list(self, request):
    today_date = date_picker

    yesterday = AllGames.objects.filter(
        date=today_date(-1)).order_by('start_time', 'teams')
    today = AllGames.objects.filter(
        date=today_date(0)).order_by('start_time', 'teams')
    tomorrow = AllGames.objects.filter(
        date=today_date(1)).order_by('start_time', 'teams')

    queryset = [yesterday, today, tomorrow]
    games = []
    for day in queryset:
        serializer = GamesSerializer(day, many=True)
        games.append(serializer.data)
    return Response(games)
```

Output I get there after.

```
[
    [{'teams': "team a -team b", 'start_time': "0: 11", 'pick': "X2", 'score': "1:4", 'odds': 1.25, 'won_or_lost': "won", 'date': "2019-01-8"}],

    [{'teams': "team a -team b", 'start_time': "0: 11", 'pick': "X2", 'score': "1:4", 'odds': 1.25, 'won_or_lost': "won", 'date': "2019-01-8"}],
    [{'teams': "team a -team b", 'start_time': "0: 11", 'pick': "X2",'score': "1:4", 'odds': 1.25, 'won_or_lost': "won", 'date': "2019-01-8"}]
 ]
```

Which is now close to what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your response class from DRF `ModelViewSet` to `ViewSet`.
Then you can further parse your data before returning response, by overriding `retrieve`

As mentioned here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example